# Python function: Error with overtime while creating a wage function

Tags: python, function

I am currently trying to create a wage function using python 3.50 which goes as follows: user enters hourly pay as "x", and hours worked as "y". I am trying to implement an overtime portion where if the hours worked is greater than 40 the person is paid 1.5 times more for those extra hours. I am inputting wage (10,45) and returning 525 when I should obviously be returning 475, can anyone help me pick out my error? Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time in advance.

```
def wage(x, y):

    if y > 40:

        ehours = y - 40
        overtime = x * 1.5 * ehours
        return x * y + overtime

    else:
        return x * y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they should only be paid 0.5 extra (not 1.5 extra), so your code should look like this:

```
def wage(x, y):
  if y > 40:
      ehours = y - 40
      overtime = x * 0.5 * ehours
      return x * y + overtime
  else:
      return x * y
```

Alternatively, it might be easier (but not necessarily better) to do this:

```
def wage(x, y):
    return x * y + (0.5*x*max(y-40, 0))
```